# AjaXplorer connect to database

Tags: ajax, linux, authentication, pydio

I discovered AjaXplorer and I was wondering if there is a step by step guide of how to step up a link between the database i have read the file http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/developer-documentation/chapter-external-bridge/
but still think its too detailed

is there a step by step ajax to link the database?

Answer (score 2):

1: Replace the auth driver and conf driver in bootstrap_plugins.php with the following:

```
    "CONF_DRIVER" => array(
        "NAME"      => "sql",
        "OPTIONS"   => array(
            "SQL_DRIVER"    => array(
                "driver"    => "mysql",
                "host"      => "db_server",
                "database"  => "db_name",
                "user"      => "db_username",
                "password"  => "db_password",
            ),
            )
),    

"AUTH_DRIVER" => array(
            "NAME"          => "sql",
            //"NAME" => "remote",
            "OPTIONS"       => array(
            "SLAVE_MODE"  => true,  
                "SQL_DRIVER"    => array(
                                        "driver"    => "mysql",
                                        "host"      => "db_server",
                                        "database"  => "db_name",
                                        "user"      => "db_username",
                                        "password"  => "db_password"
                                            ),

                "LOGIN_URL" => "../login.php",  // The URL to redirect to if a non-logged user tries to access AjaXplorer
                "LOGOUT_URL" => "../logout.php",  // The URL to redirect upon login out
                "SECRET" => "ahmed",// the secret key that you will pass to the glueCode when communicating with it (see below)
                "TRANSMIT_CLEAR_PASS"   => false  // Don't touch this. It's unsafe (and useless here) to transmit clear password.
                                        )
                ),
```

2: This is if you want to login through your own login page, You must add a glucode lines when the login page after authenticating username and password:

```
define("AJXP_EXEC", true);
    $glueCode = "ajaxplorer-core-4.0.4/plugins/auth.remote/glueCode.php";
    $secret = "ahmed";

    // Initialize the "parameters holder"
    global $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS;
    $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS = array();
    $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS["secret"] = $secret;
    $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS["plugInAction"] = "login";
    $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS["autoCreate"] = false;

    // NOTE THE md5() call on the password field.
    $AJXP_GLUE_GLOBALS["login"] = array("name" => $_POST["login"], "password" => md5($_POST["password"]));

    // NOW call glueCode!
    include($glueCode);
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, Ahmed. I added it to mine and am able to see via the logs that I am successfully logging in, but when I then click the link to ajaxplorer it still has the login popup which I was hoping to bypass. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: see the lines where the user is authenticated in gluecode I remember I set that if condition to true to bypass the ajaxplorer authentication method.

Answer (score 1):

1) You cannot use bridge with SQL Auth method in AjaxPlorer without heavily modifying the code.
2) The above example is incorrect because you must specify the "remote" parameter for "NAME" or it will not attempt to make the bridge.

This is how the process works...

You tell AjaXplorer to bridge by specifying the "NAME" => "remote" for "AUTH_DRIVER" setting.
Then, AjaXplorer links with your CMS on login attempt via the AjaXplorer CMS plugin and writes a user in the users.ser (Serial File) if they do not exist.
At this point AjaXplorer does not even attempt to look at any database at all.
The database is completely bypassed weather you specify "SQL_DRIVER" => $SQL_Settings or not.
The ONLY way it will refer to the database is if "NAME" => 'sql' for "AUTH_DRIVER" setting.
But then if you use 'sql' you will NOT be able to have bridge functionality.

Personally I think this is a HUGE bug and a major annoyance.

I hope this clears up all the confusion.